# Android manifestのconfigChangesでエラーがでる

Tags: android, gradle

Android manifestに以下の値を設定していますがそこでエラーがでてビルドに失敗してしまいます。

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

このエラーはこれまでは出なかったのですが最近になってでるようになりました。これはActivityの再生成を抑止する記述ですが、Androidのビルドシステムでこの記述はDeplecatedになったのでしょうか、それとも何かのバグでしょうか、いまだで出たことがないので気になり質問させていただきました。

Comment: `build.gradle`の`targetSdkVersion`はいくつですか？

Comment: targetSdkVersionは23です。